# WSO2 ESB 4.7 - Registry Based Deployment Synchronizer

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have upgraded to ESB 4.7 recently and struggling to get the registry deployment synchronizer to work.
When starting my 2 clustered ESB instances, changes made to artifacts, e.g. proxy, seems to be reverted then rolled forward in infinite loop, sometime ending up in with the error "RESOLVE_CONFLICTS".
Looking closer, the "Last Updated" date held into the governance registry always matches the creation date. 
I was under the impression the Deployment Synchronizer was stabilized in version 4.7. Is there any known issue?
Cheers.

Comment: Registry based deployment synchronizer is in fact improved in WSO2 ESB 4.7.0. See this blog post for more info. http://emsooriyabandara.blogspot.com/2013/01/registry-based-deployment-synchronizer.html

Comment: I have indeed looked at this article. So far my setup includes an instance of Governance Registry and 2 mgmt nodes (failing to synch up). As far as I can see, clustering and registry mounting are fine.
After further testing, the looping issue appears to occur for changes made to proxies only.

Comment: Did you see this mail? http://mail.wso2.org/mailarchive/dev/2013-August/021073.html

Comment: Yes, we are configuring 2 management nodes with auto-checking turned on to allow updates in both direction. Is the registry synchronizer limited to master/slave configurations? As a work-around, I have used the SVN approach. 
I would be glad to have your opinion on this issue as Registry-based deployment synchronizer will greatly ease deployments to new environments.

Comment: Isuru, as I was checking updates on this issue, I noticed the registry-based synchronizer is not documented in the ESB documentation anymore. 
Is the SVN-based synchronization the preferred method?